# Serializing a Java Process and then De-Serializing it -- Preferrably in a non-invasive fashion

Tags: java, serialization, aspectj

I need to serialize a Java Process (to persistent storage such as a disk) followed by killing it.

Then at a later time De-serialize it and re-resurrect it at a later date.

Constraints:

1. I already have a set of process that I want to add this feature to.
2. I am therefore looking for a solution that is minimally invasive.
3. The processes have code that will re-establish connections to resources such as sockets, DBs etc.
4. What I need to do is persist the thread statuses, variables, objects, etc.

NOTE:

1. I have decent knowledge of the issues surrounding the serializing of an Object Graph.
2. Many years ago I'd conceptually figured out how to do this using AspectJ but I can't find my notes
3. This question pertains to Java Process only -- so the solution would work on say a JVM running on OSX, Linux, or Windows
4. The process in question would be refactor-able to achieve this functionality.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Java-specific question to me. You need a mechanism that can do that for any kind of process, Java or otherwise. Like hibernation.

Comment: An _arbitrary_ process, or do you have control over the process's implementatoin?

Comment: This question pertains to:
1. Java Processes 
2. A process who's code base I can refactor 
I'll update the question to reflect these clarifications

Comment: You can serialize most of the state, but you can't serialize the threads, program counters, etc, so the process can't just resume from where it left off. Your AspectJ solution couldn't possibly have done any more than that, even if you had completed it. If you really want process hibernation you need help from the operating system as Marko said,

Comment: Please define "Java process serialisation". I have an assumption what you might mean by this term, and if my assumption is right, I might be able to suggest something to you. Otherwise my answer would be pointless, so please elaborate some more.

Comment: EJP, so there is no way to serialize Threads, really that is what I was looking for -- have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @kriegaex, I basically want to freeze dry my java process (especially the Threads) and save that to say a file on disk. Re-boot the machine. Un-freeze dry my java process from disk and be on my way -- Note I've added some clarifications to my question regarding Network resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes like `Thread`, `Socket` and other `java.io` classes do not implement `Serializable` for a purpose. Having said that, the best thing I can recommend to you as a refactoring hint is to make your applications provide a clean way of saving and restoring state when triggered. As you cannot recreate the state of threads or network connections as such, depending on the problem domain you might be able to write your classes in a way which makes them transaction-safe plus you can record running transactions on shutdown and make sure that they are rescheduled/restarted after wake-up/deserialisation.

(Disclaimer: Even after you have edited your question it is so unspecific that I can only offer an educated guess and general hints in the following.)

First and foremost you are dealing with a design question here. AOP will probably be helpful in implementing this concern (it is clearly cross-cutting) ***after*** you have solved your design issues. E.g. you could have an aspect add an interface like `Interruptable` to the classes in question and connect it to functionality implementing the desired behaviour, e.g. `ObjectState interrupt()` and `void continue(ObjectState)` (all class, interface and method names are pure invention). So while you will not be able to freeze your applications in the rather magic way you seem to describe, with some hard work you might be able to save the application state in a way which at least helps you re-start it in a way which restores logical state (not technical one like socket connections, thread IDs) so the application can continue with whatever it has been doing before you froze it.

E.g. a download manager can continue downloading a file because it has previously recorded its logical state: download source, temporary file name and number of bytes already written. So even though a new network connection needs to be established to continue the download, the "transaction" does not need to restart from scratch. I assume that is what you want.

Writing down this monologue, it seems to me that part of the functionality I was describeing should probably exist in existing application servers or containers (I am not an expert there).

So when you have finally worked out a way for all relevant application classes to persist their logical state, come back and ask another question about how to best do what you want using AspectJ or so. :-)

Comment: many thanks for the answer ... I think you've outlined the issues well and I think I have an approach in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this using Java alone in a generic way. You can run a JVM in a virtual machine which can be stopped, saved on disk and restarted as needed.  Note, network connections have to be re established. There is no way to persist them in a way which can be restored transparently, as the other end will see that the socket has gone away.

Comment: Hi, I've clarified my question in that the applications must have code that gracefully re-establishes connections to resources such as network sockets, etc.

Comment: That's what I was saying. ;) The application has to know how to do this. You can't do it transparently.